# Manipulate RGBA Javascript

Tags: javascript, rgb, uint8array

In Javascript i have a Uint8Array() RGBA of image, here is console.log of this :

[image]

Here is image with rgba array as a string in HTML:

[image]

Is that possible to manipulate this array, to ex. change colors? 
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a JS algorithm of plotting a pixel to this kind of array:

```
function changeColor(x, y, c)
{
   colorArray[(x * 4) + (y * (imageWidth * 4))] = c.r;
   colorArray[(x * 4) + (y * (imageWidth * 4)) + 1] = c.g;
   colorArray[(x * 4) + (y * (imageWidth * 4)) + 2] = c.b;
   colorArray[(x * 4) + (y * (imageWidth * 4)) + 3] = c.a;
}
```

where x and y are the coordinates of the pixel you want to change, imageWidth being the width of the image this array produces, c being the colour you want to change the pixel to, and colorArray is the array itself.

Comment: Apply the above algorithm to the `rgba` array (i. e. replace "colorArray" with "rgba" and "imageWidth" with the width of your actual image). PS: Please do not post another questions as answers to your own question. If you have something you want to know in an answer, post a comment under it.

Comment: i did like you said, and i try console.log(c), then i get error - "TypeError: c is undefined". Thanks for help!

Comment: c is the color you want to change to. Create a Color type with properties r, g, b, & a and the constructor with parameters (r, g, b, a) and then declare a variable c it like so: `var c = new Color(r, g, b, a)`.

Comment: now i get in console.log error = "Color is not defined
". Thanks for help!