# Change color rgba Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, rgba, uint8array

Here is my JS code :

```
 UTIF._imgLoaded = function(e)
            {
                var page = UTIF.decode(e.target.response)[0], rgba = UTIF.toRGBA8(page), w=page.width, h=page.height;


                var string = rgba.join();
                console.log("rgba : ", rgba);

                var ind = UTIF._xhrs.indexOf(e.target), img = UTIF._imgs[ind];
                UTIF._xhrs.splice(ind,1);  UTIF._imgs.splice(ind,1);
                var cnv = document.createElement("canvas");  cnv.width=w;  cnv.height=h;
                var ctx = cnv.getContext("2d"), imgd = ctx.createImageData(w,h);
                for(var i=0; i<rgba.length; i++) imgd.data[i]=rgba[i];       ctx.putImageData(imgd,0,0);
                var attr = ["style","class","id"];
                for(var i=0; i<attr.length; i++) cnv.setAttribute(attr[i], img.getAttribute(attr[i]));
                img.parentNode.replaceChild(cnv,img);

                document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = string;
            }
```

I get a Uint8Array() RGBA of image, here is console.log of this :
[image]

Here is image with rgba array as a string in HTML:

[image]

Is that possible to manipulate this array, to ex. change colors? Thanks for help!

Comment: Is your goal to change the image visually? Or do you want to able modify the array so that the image updates according to your change? Those two are different things but one is a lot easier to achieve I think.

Comment: @maxpaj i want to able modify the array so that the image updates according to my change. Have you any idea how to do it?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117495/how-to-create-an-image-from-array-of-pixel-colors-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manipulate RGBA Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47737257/manipulate-rgba-javascript)